# Send passwort to passwd automatically

Tags: linux, send, expect, passwd

I have a script, which is installing a guest machine on a xen server.

It installs automatically.
But in one step, I'll be asked for a password.

The following happens:

```
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

How can I send the password "1234" at this time?
Maybe with expect and send?

Here is the command, which executes passwd:

```
chroot /mnt/vms/install /usr/bin/passwd root
```

It's an internal server, so it must not be very secure.

Answer (score 0):

I have used "chpasswd" command in script, after useradd, to do that. For example

```
useradd -m -s /bin/bash -u 1001 -g 1003 -G sudo newuser || exit 1
echo newuser:newuserpassword | chpasswd || exit 1
```

Refer to [debianadmin](http://www.debianadmin.com/update-passwords-in-batch-mode-using-chpasswd.html) or [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chpasswd).